# How to calculate impact of quantitative x variables on a y variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, linear-regression, percentage

I have been trying to share some contribution analysis with management using quantitative variable. However I am struggling to reconcile my y% increase to my x's. I have tried linear regression but dont think that will help immensely here. Please help...

Here is the data and below that is the template I need to submit

[image: Data and Template]

Comment: You might want to try mathoverflow, since this sounds like a analytics problem. Although; there is some bleed over. So, not sure which would be better, but might be worth your time to also check out that other section of stackoverflow, known as mathoverflow. Someone might also answer it here, but like I said, you might find better luck there.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to correlate? A linear regression is perfectly applicable to responses that are percentages, but what are the predictor variables you're interested in?

Comment: I am not looking at predictive analytics. Wanted to add how much upward movement in the throughput was due to the mentioned factors